# I am creating an incremental game and I am struggling to get two images to be relative to each other

Tags: css, image, position

In this incremental game, you click to receive gold. The gold value is presented next to a gold icon. The problem is when the value becomes a high enough digit, it overlaps the icon. I want to make it so when the number value becomes a high enough digit the gold icon moves slightly to the left in order to prevent being overlapped. This is what I have as of now ↓

```
#text{
color: gold;
display:block;
position: absolute;
top: 275px;
right: 100px;}

#gold{
display:block;
position: absolute;
top: 285px;
right: 125px; }
```

Comment: You either need to make your box bigger to support more digits or you are going to need to use javascript to expand the box dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep image proportion using calc (width - X)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635500/how-to-keep-image-proportion-using-calc-width-x)

Answer (score 0):

Other than what @Rick said, you could give `#text` a `width` value, and set `text-align:center` so it always stays in the same spot no matter how large the number.